# How change colums for rows in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a survey with many objectives for assess from 1 to 5 in my web page. I send the survey to my database in my table of survey. 
For example

```
 obj1value | obj2value | obj3value ...  | obj17value |
```

I have a value for every survey.

Now I need to do some charts for present a report of the survey.
I need to add up the totals for each objective. 
I have this query

```
SELECT SUM(obj1_value) AS objective1, SUM(obj2_value) AS objective2, SUM(obj3_value) AS objective3, FROM tbl_survey
```

I have this till objective17 and the query returns

```
| objective1 | objective2 | objective3 | 
|   ---      |    ---     |    ---     |
|    17      |     12     |    5       |
```

But I need to change the query like this

```
_objective_ | _Value_           
objective1  | 17 
objective2  | 12 
objective3  | 5  
Objective17 |  n
```

Someone can help me with the query to optimize because in this way I can convert the table php in json and took a bar chart library so easy.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easiest to do the transformation in PHP.  One method in MySQL is a simple `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'obj1_value', SUM(obj1_value) 
FROM tbl_survey
UNION ALL
SELECT 'obj2_value', SUM(obj2_value) 
FROM tbl_survey
UNION ALL
. . .
```

The downside to this approach is that the table is scanned 17 times, so it will probably take about 17 times as long.

You can improve performance by doing an unpivot.  Here is one method in MySQL:

```
SELECT o.obj,
       (CASE WHEN obj = 'objective1' THEN objective1
             WHEN obj = 'objective2' THEN objective2
             . . .
        END) as value
FROM (SELECT SUM(obj1_value) AS objective1, SUM(obj2_value) AS objective2, 
             SUM(obj3_value) AS objective3, . . .
      FROM tbl_survey
     ) s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 'objective1' as obj UNION ALL
      SELECT 'objective2' as obj UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) o;
```

Comment: The first option works perfect, but I will try the second, because I need save the result set in one call, not in 17 times. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the solution for this problem is PIVOT AN UNPOVIT , and you can change the out put us you want , [this is tutorial can help you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx?ppud=4)